# Ish Yehudi - where else?

Tags: words, tanach, megillat-esther

Where else in Tanach are there the words "Ish Yehudi" besides Megilas Esther?

Comment: LMGTFY.........

Comment: @ShmuelBrill http://bit.ly/Aj7Fkj but ironically THIS is the first hit!

Comment: @none why the up votes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

זכריה ח כג

אמר יהוה צבאות בימים ההמה אשר יחזיקו עשרה אנשים מכל לשנות הגוים והחזיקו בכנף איש יהודי לאמר נלכה עמכם כי שמענו אלהים עמכם

Yalkut Shimoni on Esther:אסתר - פרק ב - רמז תתרנג

דבר אחר איש יהודי עליו נאמר מה שהיה הוא שיהיה, מה הגדולה נעשית על ידי איש יהודי, אף גאולה לעתיד כך, שנאמר בימים ההם אשר יחזיקו עשרה אנשים מכל לשונות הגוים והחזיקו בכנף איש יהודי לאמר נלכה עמכם וגו'

Comment: Any Divrei Torah as to the connection of the 2?

Comment: Well, the Gemara (Shabbos 32b) relates the verse in Zechariah to careful observance of the mitzvah of tzitzis (based on the word "כנף"). Someone says (I don't recall the source) that Mordechai's לבוש מלכות תכלת וחור was in fact a tallis with tzitzis - and it led to ורבים מעמי הארץ מתיהדים, many of the non-Jews professing Judaism.

Comment: @Gershon, The question you put in a comment here is much more interesting than the one you asked as a question.

Answer (score 7):

[דניאל ג:יב](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3403.htm#12add)

איתי **גברין יהודאין** די מנית יתהון על עבידת מדינת בבל שדרך מישך ועבד נגו גבריא אלך לא שמו עליך עלך מלכא טעם לאלהיך לאלהך לא פלחין ולצלם דהבא די הקימת לא סגדין:

It's in Aramaic, but I think it still counts.

Comment: Indeed, the Gemara (Megillah 13a) uses this as proof of the idea that "anyone who denies avodah zarah is called [by the title] Yehudi" - like Mordechai for his refusal to bow to Haman.

Comment: @Alex Indeed, I wish I could say I had good enough bekius in Daniyel to know this pasuk off hand...