# Why is מרדכי the only one called a "יהודי?"

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, tractate-megillah

In Tractate [Megilah 13a](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.13a.2?lang=he) - it explains that מרדכי was called an איש יהודי, since he went against עבודה זרה.

If so - then why is he the only one called a "יהודי?"

Why not משה? Or אברהם? Or דוד? Or יוסף?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6186/759

Comment: my question is, if so that one who goes against Avodah Zara is called Yehudi - then why isn't every Gadol called Yehudi?

Comment: Probably because Yehudi is anyway the term used to describe Jews in the Megilla (and onwards to this day!), because the population was mainly Judeans. The issue is that Mordechai wasn't from Yehuda so the gemara is discussing if the term is accurate, but underlying it is that it had become a catchall.